# Prompt user to save file to a specific location

Tags: php, html, location, download

I'm creating a website that generates a text file.  I would like for the user to save the file to a specific folder (it's a backup file for a video game).

Is it possible to change the default folder the file is saved to via PHP or HTML?  C#, while not my first pick, would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, NO you cannot default to a location on the users computer.  This is just a security piece that you cannot get around.

Try educating the user before they download. That's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

No file download locations are handle at the browser level

Answer (score 1):

You could probably package the text file in an installer / extractor that loads it to the location you want, but I don't think you want to go that far ^.^

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prompt the user to save the file to a specific place on his/her computer, you can however save some stuff on the users pc by the use of [Web Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage), that is a part of the HTML5 spec. You will not be able to control where it will be saved though.

It would not be a smart move to store backups for your game on the users pc, as it would open a endless world of cheating and hacking.