# How to save downloading file to specific location using PHP

Tags: php

Here I am generate the dot RTF file for $report_content content.
It's successfully generated dot RTF file.
No need file download option and I want to move some location.
How to do?

```
<?php
//load the rtf template as a string     
$email_id = 'ram@gmail.com';    
$file_dir = 'uploads/';
$report_content = "
<html>
    <body>
        Hello, This is testing<br /><br />
        message.    
    </body>
</html>";

//and now serve the file as an rtf download:
echo $report_content;

header("Content-type: application/rtf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=rtf.rtf"); //How to save in $file_dir
exit();
```

Please update any other ways.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405180/prompt-user-to-save-file-to-a-specific-location

Answer (score 0):

1)its not possible due to security issue.

2)you have to suggest the user to save particular location

Comment: Is there any other ways?